# Segmentation fault while trying to arrange words alphabetically in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and i am trying to write a code which sorts out alphabetically some words that i give from console. 
I dont know why but i get segmentation fault error. Can you please help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int arrange (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  //return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
    return (strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b));
}

int main() {
    char words[50][50];
    int i=0, n;
    cout << "Enter the number of words to be ordered:";
    cin >> n; 
    int length = 0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> words[i];
        cout << words[i];
    }

    qsort(words, n, sizeof(words[0]), &arrange);
}
```

This is how my code looks like

Comment: Program does not compile. Provide a minimal working example. Also bear in mind that C++ is more than "C with cin and cout".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a C question.  The qsort routine passes in two values: not pointers to the values; therefore your comparison should be

```
int arrange (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return (strcmp((const char *)a, (const char *)b));
}
```

Comment: Print the array after the qsort

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more C-like than C++.  You should use `vector`, and `string`, and `sort`.  And check your input for failure.

Also, your code should be cut-n-paste compilable.  You are missing headers and `using` statements.

Your use of `qsort` (a C routine) won't work in the way you are using it.  C++ provides `sort`, which is much more suitable for the problem you are solving.

For example...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::begin;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::end;
using std::ostream;
using std::sort;
using std::runtime_error;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

static ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, vector<string> const& words) {
    char const* sep = "";

    for(auto const& word : words) {
        o << sep << word;
        sep = ", ";
    }

    return o;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> words;
    cout << "Dati nr de cuvinte de ordonat:";
    int n;
    if (!(cin >> n)) throw runtime_error("bad input");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        string word;
        if (!(cin >> word)) throw runtime_error("bad input");
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    cout << "Before sorting: " << words << "\n";
    sort(begin(words), end(words));
    cout << "After sorting: " << words << "\n";
}
```